# How to reset form and delete Cookie after clicking on reset button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am saving the drop down selections in a cookie called "mysettings".  However, after running through the program (myform.htm) first time and saved the selections of these two fields in the cookie, on the second run, I want to delete the cookie and reset both drop down boxes on clicking the Reset button at the same time.

MYFORM.HTM:

```
<form action="myform.htm" method="post" >
    Field 1: <select name="f1">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
    </select> 
    Field 2: <select name="f2">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="reset" value ="Reset" onclick= 'document.cookie = "mysettings=; expires=Fri, 29 Jun 2018 00:00:00 GMT; path/";'/>  &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="action" value=" Submit ">
</form>
```

However, it does not delete the cookie nor reset the form.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

--- EDITED ---
I have found the issue with deleting the cookie.  It was missing a SECURE parameter. The cookie was secured by Coldfusion but the cookie deletion is missing that parameter, therefore it won't delete.   So now I have:

```
<form action="myform.htm" method="post" >
    Field 1: <select name="f1">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
    </select> 
    Field 2: <select name="f2">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="reset" value ="Reset" onclick= "clearset()">  &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="action" value=" Submit ">
</form>

<script>
function clearset () {
    document.cookie = "mysettings=; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; secure; path=/"; 
    window.location.reload();
}       
</script>
```

Now the cookie gets deleted, however, the Reset will still not reset the fields. The reason I believe was due to the fields were "selected" based on the stored cookie value.  Even though the cookie was deleted, the page doesn't know that.  So a reload is most likely required?  But even with the reload, the fields are **still not reset**!  I had to press the Reset key again to reset it.   Is there a way to reload and reset the fields automatically or totally avoid reload altogether?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp - says while deleting a cookie you may have to specify path, otherwise it will not be deleted.  You may be getting javascript error that is why the form is not resetting either.  Use code inspector to see what is the error.

Comment: @T.Shah I have added the path but it still doesn't work.  Didn't see javascript error either.  Maybe Reset type can't have onclick?

Comment: If you are willing to move from Cookies to localStorage, managing them is easier IMO.

Comment: @imvain2 I will still need the same Reset button to work.  Can you give an example how to reset with local storage?

Comment: What's this got to do with ColdFusion? This is all mark-up and client-side JS..?

Comment: @AdamCameron The program is in Coldfusion. Cookie set by Coldfusion also.  Just need to find a way to delete the cookie and reset the value one way or another.  Coldfusion solution is also workable.

Answer (score 0):

now that you fixed cookies, I think it should be easy to reset form values according to here [Form reset() Method w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

just use

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

no need for reload

Comment: I tried it before.  Unfortunately, it does not work.  If deleting cookie will make Reset work, there is no need to reload.  As mentioned, before the page was loaded, the page got the values from the cookie.  So when the cookie is deleted, the page would still have "selected" in the fields.  The page does not know the cookie is gone. All it knows is those selected values, in fact, are the default values.  It will look for the cookie again only by reloading.  Since it does not have one, then it will load the real default (e.g. First).  But somehow, the values were still retained.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution!  Simple as it may sound, adding a "true" to the reload() function fixed it!

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Apparently, Firefox and Chrome etc. don't really reload with the reload().  Adding that parameter seems to do a force reload.  It must have been a [hidden feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)